# Swift 2.0 if statement in table view cell

Tags: if-statement, swift2, uitableview

I am trying to display the contents of an array in table view cells.
I created the arrays (I have one array of images and three arrays of strings).

I managed to display the contents of the arrays without any issues. 
Here is my viewController.swift :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var shopOpen: Bool = false


var openSign: UIImage = UIImage(named: "open")!
var closedSign: UIImage = UIImage(named: "closed")!



var logos = [UIImage(named: "shop1"), UIImage(named: "shop2"), UIImage(named: "shop3")]
var programWorkingDays = ["Luni-Vineri:09:00-20:00", "Luni-Vineri::10:00-21:00", "Luni-Vineri:09:30-19:30"]
var programSambata = ["Sambata:10:00-16:00","Sambata:10:30-13:00" ,"Sambata: 09:00-13:00"]
var programDuminica = ["Duminica:10:00-15:00","Duminica:09:00-14:00","Duminica:10:30-15:00"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.logo.image = logos[indexPath.row]
    cell.programWorkingDays.text = programWorkingDays[indexPath.row]
    cell.programSambata.text = programSambata[indexPath.row]
    cell.programDuminica.text = programDuminica[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

}

My next goal is to display one image or another based on a true/false value of a variable (shopOpen)

If the variable is true i want to have picture 1, if it's false i want to have picture 2.
The image view is placed in the main.storyboard and the connection is made in the cell class.

The images will be storet in UIImage variables (given the fact that i only have two images for this part, i don't think it makes any sense to put them inside an array)

Where should i write the if statement and how do i refresh the cells to display the correct image ?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I  edited my initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, rather than multiple arrays for the parameters use a struct including an boolean `open` property

```
struct Shop {
  var workingDays : String
  var sambata : String
  var duminica : String

  var logo : UIImage?

  var open = false
}
```

In the `ViewController` class declare a variable `shops` as an empty `Shop` array

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  let openSign: UIImage = UIImage(named: "open")!
  let closedSign: UIImage = UIImage(named: "closed")!

  var shops = [Shop]()
```

In `viewDidLoad` populate the `shops` array with appropriate `Shop` instances

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    shops.append(Shop(workingDays: "09:00-20:00", sambata: "10:00-16:00", duminica: "10:00-15:00", logo: UIImage(named: "shop1"), open: true))
    shops.append(Shop(workingDays: "10:00-21:00", sambata: "10:30-13:00", duminica: "09:00-14:00", logo: UIImage(named: "shop2"), open: false))
    shops.append(Shop(workingDays: "09:30-19:30", sambata: "09:00-13:00", duminica: "10:30-15:00", logo: UIImage(named: "shop3"), open: true))
  }
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return the number of shops rather than a hard-coded integer

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shops.count
  }
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` display the values from the `Shop` instances. Assuming there is an image view `openImage` the open or close image is displayed depending on the state of the `open` property.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
    let shop = shops[indexPath.row]
    cell.logo.image = shop.logo
    cell.programWorkingDays.text = "Luni-Vineri: \(shop.workingDays)"
    cell.programSambata.text = "Sambata: \(shop.sambata)"
    cell.programDuminica.text = "Duminica: \(shop.duminica)"
    cell.openImage.image = shop.open ? openSign : closedSign
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the : cell.openImage.image = shop.open ? openSign : closedSign does (especially the "?" ) .  Can i run a function inside the cell generation process to check the status of the shop ? The mechanism i choose is the following : i'm using nsdate to get the weekday as an int, with this method and an if statement i find out in what kind of day i'm currently in (working day, saturday or sunday). Then i'm running nsdate functions to get the hour and the minute. With this info i set the open or closed option for each shop.

Comment: The line assigns `openSign` to `cell.openImage.image` if the `open` property is `true` otherwise `closedSign`. It's a short form for `if - else` Just set the property in the model and reload the table view.